# How to check Win/Loss for each hero in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Before one of the last patches it was possible but after the introduction of "Performance Index" I don't see anymore the possibility to check the number of Wins and Losses for each hero.

Only 3 most played heroes are shown.

[image: Most player heroes]

How to see W/L of all heroes, maybe using some console commands?

Comment: what happens if you click that small "more" button on the bottom left of your screen shot :P

Comment: oh, I see it brings up teh performance index thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With latest Dota 2 patch (25/05/12), Valve added the possibility to see Win/Loss stats for all hero directly with game client, in the Account Details.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of now (29/04/2012), you can't. There is an *external service* who provides it, though.

It's this website: http://stats.dota2.be/. You have to create an account associated with your Steam account, so people won't be able to see others' individual stats. It seems they get their information from data mining every match played.

I'm not affiliated in any way with them, so I can't comment about security or anything. However, linking your Steam account is safe, as it uses the Steam API. In any case, I would recommend using a different password for this site.

Comment: Nice link, it has indeed many more stats than what Dota 2 client offers at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use a third-party service called [DotaBuff](http://dotabuff.com/):

[image: My Stats on DotaBuff]

I prefer it over the in-game tools because, as you can see, it has way more information available than just your win/loss count.